# Mongodb lookup aggregation on array of embedded documents

Tags: mongodb

I have an "issues" collection

```js
{
   _id: "ISSUE-1",
   contact_id: "CONT-1"
}
```

And an "organizations" collection

```js
{
    _id: "ORG-1",
    organizationContacts: [
        { _id: "CONT-1", name: "John Doe" },
        { _id: "CONT-2", name: "Jane Doe" )
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to build an aggregate query that will return an "issue" and specific "contact" data that is linked to it like so:

```js
{
    _id: "ISSUE-1",
    contactName: "John Doe"
}
```

so far I've tried:

```js
db.getCollection('issues')
  .aggregate([
 { 
   $lookup: {
     from: 'organizations',
     localField: 'contact_id',
     foreignField: 'organizationContacts._id',
     as: 'contactInfo'
   }
 }
```

but that returns the organization with the entire organizationContacts array like:

```js
{
     _id: "ISSUE-1",
     contactInfo: { 
       _id: "ORG-1",
       organizationContacts: [
           { _id: "CONT-1", name: "John Doe" },
           { _id: "CONT-2", name: "Jane Doe" }
       ]
     }
}
```

Anyway to achieve this with one query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best approach, but I have tested it and it works.

```
[{$lookup: {
  from: 'organizations',
  localField: 'contact_id',
  foreignField: 'organizationContacts._id',
  as: 'contactInfo'
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$contactInfo"
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$contactInfo.organizationContacts"
}}, {$match: {
  "$expr": { "$eq": ["$contactInfo.organizationContacts._id", "$contact_id"]}
}}, {$project: {
  "_id": 1,
  "contactName": "$contactInfo.organizationContacts.name"
}}]
```

1. First we do a [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) as you did it.

```
{
  "_id" : "ISSUE-1",
  "contact_id" : "CONT-1",
  "contactInfo" : [
    {
      "_id" : "ORG-1",
      "organizationContacts" : [
        {
          "_id" : "CONT-1",
          "name" : "John Doe"
        },
        {
          "_id" : "CONT-2",
          "name" : "Jane Doe"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

2. [Unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) `contactInfo` to get from an array to a single object. This will not increase the number of documents.

```
{
  "_id" : "ISSUE-1",
  "contact_id" : "CONT-1",
  "contactInfo" : {
    "_id" : "ORG-1",
    "organizationContacts" : [
      {
        "_id" : "CONT-1",
        "name" : "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "CONT-2",
        "name" : "Jane Doe"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

3. [Unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) `organizationContact` to get from an array of `contactInfo.organizationContacts` to an array of documents which each contain a different contact. Now we have 2 documents (given your example).

```
[
  {
    "_id" : "ISSUE-1",
    "contact_id" : "CONT-1",
    "contactInfo" : {
      "_id" : "ORG-1",
      "organizationContacts" : {
        "_id" : "CONT-1",
        "name" : "John Doe"
      },
    }
  }
  {
    "_id" : "ISSUE-1",
    "contact_id" : "CONT-1",
    "contactInfo" : {
      "_id" : "ORG-1",
      "organizationContacts" : {
        "_id" : "CONT-2",
        "name" : "Jane Doe"
      },
    }
  }
]
```

4. Then we [match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) only the documents with same `contactInfo.organizationContacts._id"` and `contact_id` to only get the correct contact. This reduces our output back to one document for each issue.

```
{
  "_id" : "ISSUE-1",
  "contact_id" : "CONT-1",
  "contactInfo" : {
    "_id" : "ORG-1",
    "organizationContacts" : {
      "_id" : "CONT-1",
      "name" : "John Doe"
    },
  }
}
```

5. Finally we [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) to get the fields we want

```
{
  "_id" : "ISSUE-1",
  "contactName" : "John Doe"
}
```

Comment: very cool! it works for me too. I'm at a stage in my project  where i'm looking for "a approach" not necessarily "the best approach" ;) Thanks a lot!!!